# Different ways of inserting into a table LUA

Tags: lua

Okay, so i come down to a dilemma that I can't seem to solve in LUA.

Basically I am trying to insert values into a table, and i am trying to insert it like this:

```
 activeContracts = {
        [user_id] = {
            [1] = {
                source = src
            }
        }
    }
```

But not in that style but instead of this style:

```
    activeContracts = {}
    activeContracts[user_id][1]["source"] = src
```

But the last example doesn't work. I've googled around and I can't seem to find any documentation that displays my dilemma.

If anyone experienced in LUA can comment on this it would mean alot.

Regards.

Comment: See http://lua-users.org/wiki/AutomagicTables

Answer (score 1):

`activeContracts = {}` creates an empty global table.

`activeContracts[user_id][1]["source"] = src` attempts to assign `scr` to `activeContracts[user_id][1]["source"]` But you may not index `activeContracts[user_id][1]` because it does not exist.
You may also not index `activeContracts[user_id]` for the same reason.

So you're trying to assign values to a nested tables that do not exist. You have to create that nested structure first. You're basically trying to enter a room in the third floor of a house you never built.

```
activeContracts =  {[user_id] = {{}}}
```

Comment: Can you show an example on how to create the nested structure?

Comment: This did not create the desired result. I tried that: activeContracts =  {[user_id] = {{}}} activeContracts["source"] = src outputs: {"51928":[[]],"source":10} when i want it to output: {"51928":[{"source":10}]}

Comment: either do it manually or use the link lhf provided. you may not index nil values. hence you can only add elements to tables that already exist.

Comment: `activeContracts["source"] = src` will add `src` to `activeContracts`  you need to do this: `activeContracts[user_id][1]["source"] = src`. your initial assignment was correct. you just failed to create table structure first

Comment: Yea i did the table structure you suggested and It works now. But whenever i try to add more entries it says "Attempt to index a nil value (field 'integer index'') What I am trying:    activeContracts[user_id][1]["source"] = src
    activeContracts[user_id][2]["source"] = src

Comment: well did you create a table `activeContracts[user_id][2]`? probably not so you cannot add values to it... you cannot index nil values. so if you write something like `activeContracts[user_id][2]["source"]` make sure you actually have a table `activeContracts[user_id][2]`  or that indexing operation is forbidden beacuse it doesn't make any sense. write a function that constructs that data structure for you so you don't have to manually do this. and realize what an indexin operation is and where it is allowed